# Question about integrality and algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ and $B$ be both $k$-algebras. Suppose $B$ is integral over $A$, and also that $B$ and $A$ are integral domains.

Let us denote $F(B)$ and $F(A)$ as the field of fractions of $B$ and $A$ respectively. Does it then follow that $F(B)$ is an algebraic extension of $F(A)$?

Comment: Let $y/z$ be an element of the field of fractions $F(B)$. Try constructing a polynomial over $F(A)$, of which $y/z$ is a root, using the integral equation of $y$ over $A$.

Comment: @basket Could I possibly get a little more hint for this approach?

Comment: Try just plugging $y/z$ into the integral equation for $y$. It wont equal zero, but with a little modification to the coefficients...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ K = F(A) $ and let $ x/y \in F(B) $, with $ x, y \in B $. Then, since $ x $ and $ y $ are integral over $ A $, the extension $ K(x, y) $ is of finite degree over $ K $. On the other hand, $ x/y $ is contained in this extension...